# Say we have a double-decker Lazy Susan with two levels that can be turned independently. If we have n + k dishes in total, how many ways

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, discrete-mathematics

Say we have a double-decker Lazy Susan with two levels that can be turned independently. If we have n + k dishes in total, how many ways 
[image]

**is that solution is correct ???**

[image]

Comment: We need to choose the ones for the top, $\binom{n+k}{k}$ ways. Then for dealing with the arrangements, multiply by $(k-1)!(n-1)!$.

Comment: can you give me more explanation

Comment: I'd like to wait a bit before posting a full solution (but someone may post one soon).  Ideally I would like you to take the brief analysis of the comment and see why it gives a solution. The material of your post is *part* of the solution, it deals with the arrangement of dishes on top and bottom once it has been decided who goes on top.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first choose which *k* dishes will go to the top level, in ${n+k\choose k}$ ways.

The balance *n* dishes automatically get assigned to the bottom level.

You then need to apply the permutation formula for arrangements in a circle (which has already been quoted by you, to *both* levels, thus

$$(k-1)!(n-1)!{n+k\choose k}$$